# React Router withRouter compatibility with AWS AppSync Provider

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-apollo, aws-appsync

I have a React app that uses Apollo ([react-apollo)](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/) and also [AWS AppSync React](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-appsync-react). I'm trying to wrap my React app with the `Provider` component as described in the docs, but also wrapping my app within `withRouter` from the `react-router` package so that I can then redirect the app on successful logout & login. I currently have the bootstrapped CRA structure of `App.js` & `index.js`

```
// index.js

import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import AppContainer from "./App";
import { LoadingScreen } from "./components";

import Amplify from "aws-amplify";

import AWSAppSyncClient from "aws-appsync";
import { Rehydrated } from "aws-appsync-react";
import { ApolloProvider } from "react-apollo";

Amplify.configure({
  ...
});

const client = new AWSAppSyncClient({
  ...
});

const WithProvider = () => (
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <Rehydrated render={({ rehydrated }) => (rehydrated ? <AppContainer /> : <LoadingScreen />)}>
      <AppContainer />
    </Rehydrated>
  </ApolloProvider>
);

ReactDOM.render(<WithProvider />, document.getElementById("root"));


// App.js

import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { BrowserRouter, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { hot } from "react-hot-loader";

import { Auth } from "aws-amplify";

import ScrollToTop from "./config/ScrollToTop";
import { Navbar } from "./components";
import Routes from "./config/routes";

class AppContainer extends Component {
  static displayName = "AppContainer";
  static propTypes = {
    history: PropTypes.array
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isAuthenticated: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    ...
  }

  userHasAuthenticated = authenticated => {
    ...
  }

  handleLogout = async () => {
    await Auth.signOut();
    this.userHasAuthenticated(false);
    window.location.replace("/");
  }

  render() {
    const childProps = {
      isAuthenticated: this.state.isAuthenticated,
      userHasAuthenticated: this.userHasAuthenticated,
      handleLogout: this.handleLogout
    };
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <ScrollToTop>
        { !this.state.isAuthenticating &&
          <Fragment>
            <Navbar childProps={childProps} />
            <Routes childProps={childProps} />
          </Fragment>
        }
        </ScrollToTop>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(hot(module)(AppContainer));
```

When trying to run my app, I get `You should not use <Route> or withRouter() outside a <Router>` - I've tried `export default hot(module)(withRouter(AppContainer));` to no avail.

Comment: Extract the `<ScrollToTop> ... </...>` component tree into a functional component by itself, wrap that in the higher order, then reference it inside of `<BrowserRouter>...</...>`

Answer (score 0):

Tom,

Are you using Cognito User Pools as auth method. If that is the case I suggest you to use aws-amplify, is very simple to wrap a react app with authenticator component or withAuthenticator HOC. Take a look [here](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication#using-components-in-react--react-native)